# Starting and stopping python script, but running for set amount of time

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a linear actuator hooked up to a raspberry pi that is turned on and off with a button push. I want that actuator to move for a TOTAL prescribed amount of time. Example: The total time I want the actuator to run is 5 seconds. If a user pushes the button to start the actuator, it begins moving. Then after 3 seconds the user pushes the button again it stops. Then if they push it again, it starts moving, and automatically stops after 5 seconds. Here is the code I have for running the motor with the push button, I just want to integrate the timing now. Any ideas?

```
from Adafruit_MotorHAT import Adafruit_MotorHAT, Adafruit_DCMotor
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import atexit
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.IN)

# create a default object, no changes to I2C address or frequency
mh = Adafruit_MotorHAT(addr=0x60)

# recommended for auto-disabling motors on shutdown!
def turnOffMotors():
   mh.getMotor(1).run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.RELEASE)
   mh.getMotor(2).run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.RELEASE)
   mh.getMotor(3).run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.RELEASE)
   mh.getMotor(4).run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.RELEASE)

atexit.register(turnOffMotors)

################################# DC motor test!
myMotor = mh.getMotor(3)

# set the speed to start, from 0 (off) to 255 (max speed)
myMotor.setSpeed(255)
myMotor.run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.FORWARD);
# turn on motor
myMotor.run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.RELEASE);


snooziness = 5
stateOn = 0
stateOff = 0
while (True):

    if(GPIO.input(23)== False) and (stateOn==0):
       myMotor.run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.FORWARD)
       sleep(snooziness)
       myMotor.run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.RELEASE)
       stateOn=1

    if(GPIO.input(23)== False) and (stateOn==1):
       myMotor.run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.RELEASE)
       stateOn=0


    if(GPIO.input(24)== False) and (stateOff==0):
       myMotor.run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.BACKWARD)
       sleep(snooziness)
       myMotor.run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.RELEASE)
       stateOff=1

    if(GPIO.input(24)== False) and (stateOff==1):
       myMotor.run(Adafruit_MotorHAT.RELEASE)
       stateOn=0

    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
import time

running = False
stop_time = None

while(True):
    if(buttonPushed()):
        if running:
            running = False
            stop_motor()
            stop_time = None
        else
            running = True
            start_motor()
            stop_time = time.time() + 5
    if stop_time is not None and time.time() > stop_time():
        running = False
        stop_motor()
        stop_time = None
```

I think that demonstrates the logic I'd use, although there's clearly some code redundancy there that could be tidied up